# How to distribute my sass variables to all React components?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I´m trying to import my **_variables.scss** into my root styles to have all styles in all my components. Check it

```
/*Importing my lib styles*/
@import "./libs/_variables.scss";

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

@import "./pages/login/components/header/Header";
```

But it show this error.

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$primary-color".
        on line 2 of src/pages/login/components/header/Header.scss
>>   background-color: $primary-color;
   --------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to import _variables.scss inside Header.scss

Comment: I dont want to do it, think if i need to import _variables into all my components... pff

Comment: @DiegoCardona, please have a look into the another answer I have posted

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it just imports any scss file from your root index.scss

so rather than placing import './Header.scss'; in Header.js
You do

```
@import "./_variables.scss";
@import "./components/Header/Header.scss";
```

in index.scss

and import './index.scss' in index.js

Comment: That´s what I do

Comment: There is bit difference you are importing Header.scss in Header.js, instead you have to import all in centralized main scss file and and import all other scss file over there